# How to reference enumerations defined inside a subclass

Tags: c++, namespaces

Suppose I have the following base class:

```
class LongComplexClassName
{
    public:
       enum Blar { First, Second, Third };
       void useBlar() { doSomething( First ); } // works.
};

class MyClass : public LongComplexClassName
{
    void useBlar() { doSomething( First ); } // error: wants LongComplexClassName::First
};

void nakedFunction()
{
    doSomething( First ); // same error...
};
```

Is there a way, by adding "using" declarations to allow me to refer to "First" without fully qualifying it? I can do this with namespaces. But can it be done when the enumeration is defined as part of a base class?

Comment: :Use LongComplexClassName::First

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Allow reference to `First` without fully qualifying it

> Is there a way, by adding "using" declarations to allow me to refer to
>   "First" without fully qualifying it?

No, but an `enum` could be dealt with on its own terms.

---

For a `using` or a `typedef` declaration we must use a type. So

- `LongComplexClassName::Blar` would be a type, but
- `LongComplexClassName::Blar::First` is a value.

---

### Use unqualified `First` without an extra declaration

In the following program we can pass `First` to `doSomething()`. In the classes we don't need anything declared.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename T>
void doSomething(const T& t)
{
    std::cout << typeid(t).name() << ":";
    std::cout << t << '\n';
}

class LongComplexClassName {
public:
    enum Blar { First,Second,Third };
    void useBlar() { doSomething(First); } // Works. First is an enum value
};

class MyClass : public LongComplexClassName {
public:
    void useBlar() { doSomething(First); } // Also works. First is still an enum value
};

int main()
{
    LongComplexClassName{}.useBlar();
    MyClass{}.useBlar();
    return 0;
}
```

On my system this produces:

```
enum LongComplexClassName::Blar:0
enum LongComplexClassName::Blar:0
```

---

### Reference to `First` from a non-member function

Next, for the function, if we accept `LongComplexClassName::Blar::First` is a value and declare a `const` accordingly then we can use it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename T>
void doSomething(const T& t)
{
    std::cout << typeid(t).name() << ":";
    std::cout << t << '\n';
}

class LongComplexClassName {
public:
    enum Blar { First,Second,Third };
    void useBlar() { doSomething(First); } // Works. First is an enum value
};

class MyClass : public LongComplexClassName {
public:
    void useBlar() { doSomething(First); } // Also works. First is still an enum value
};

void nakedFunction()
{
    using Blar = LongComplexClassName::Blar;
    const auto First = Blar::First;
    doSomething(First); // Works. Now First is a const variable of an enum value and can be used
}

int main()
{
    LongComplexClassName{}.useBlar();
    MyClass{}.useBlar();
    nakedFunction();

    return 0;
}
```

On my system the output is:

```
enum LongComplexClassName::Blar:0
enum LongComplexClassName::Blar:0
enum LongComplexClassName::Blar:0
```

---

### Reference to `First` as part of a `class enum`

Of course, we could also use a `class enum`. The program then requires a `const` in the class to allow for using `First` without qualifying it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
void doSomething(const T& t)
{
    std::cout << typeid(t).name() << ":";
    using ttype = std::underlying_type<T>::type;
    std::cout << static_cast<ttype>(t) << '\n';
}

class LongComplexClassName {
public:
    enum class Blar { First,Second,Third };
    const LongComplexClassName::Blar First = Blar::First;
    void useBlar() { doSomething(First); } // Works. First is a const variable of an enum value
};

class MyClass : public LongComplexClassName {
public:
    void useBlar() { doSomething(First); } // Also works. First is a const variable of an enum value
};

void nakedFunction()
{
    using Blar = LongComplexClassName::Blar;
    const auto First = Blar::First;
    doSomething(First); // Works. First is a const variable of an enum value and can be used
}

int main()
{
    LongComplexClassName{}.useBlar();
    MyClass{}.useBlar();
    nakedFunction();

    return 0;
}
```

On my system this produces:

```
enum LongComplexClassName::Blar:0
enum LongComplexClassName::Blar:0
enum LongComplexClassName::Blar:0
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, no, you cannot use "using".  That is for exposing namespace scoped names